How to get session after browser page reload in a Next 14 / Nextauth 5 page?
I use Next 14 and NextAuth v5. My session is nicely retrieved when I use the navigation bar in my application, but when I reload the page in the browser with F5, it is not returning the session (even when I am logged in.
I was expecting to get the session back in the call to getCurrentUserEmail(), also when I hit the browser F5 refresh, but it returns undefined/null. So for some reason the useSession does not return the session with a browser reload. (In-app navigation does return the session nicely when logged in however)
Is there any way how I can solve this?
"use client";

// imports

const ListPage = () => {
    const [listName, setListName] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();

    function getCurrentUserEmail(): string | null {
        return session?.user?.email || null;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const userEmail = getCurrentUserEmail();
        // rest of code
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {!showModal && (<div>Welcome to your list: {listName}</div>)}
            {showModal && (
                <div >
                    Please create your list first
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ListPage;```

